# Error Generated when Passing Drawables

Tags: java, android, android-intent, adapter, android-drawable

I am trying to reference a drawable from a resource ID that is passed through putInt() in CreateActivity. I would like to use the drawable associated with the resource ID and use it as part of creating Event Object (with other parameters).

**Am I referencing the drawable incorrectly? or is there a problem with the way I have structured the Event Object?**

Sorry for the longwinded post.

**CreateActivity**

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etTitle;
Button btDate;
Button btTime;
Button btPic;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //onclicklistener
    findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_back).setOnClickListener(this);

    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    btPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picture);

}

// Will be called via the onClick attribute
// of the buttons in main.xml
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_confirm:
        String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
        String time = btTime.getText().toString();
        String date = btDate.getText().toString();

        int resId = getResources().getInteger(R.id.btn_picture);


        Log.e("LOG", title);
        Log.e("LOG", time);
        Log.e("LOG", date);

        Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
        newBundle.putString("TITLE", title);
        newBundle.putString("TIME", time);
        newBundle.putString("DATE", date);

        //Trying to pass a drawable from one activity to another
        newBundle.putInt("DRAWABLE", resId);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(newBundle);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();

        break;

    case R.id.btn_back:
        finish();
        break;
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void showPicturePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new PicturePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "picturePicker");
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
ArrayList<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView ivPic;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;
int resId;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            // retrieving resId, creating drawable

            resId = b.getInt("DRAWABLE");
            Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(resId);

            /////

            Log.e("SWAGSWAG", title);
            Log.e("SWAGSWAG", time);
            Log.e("SWAGSWAG", date);

            Event newEvent = new Event();
            newEvent.set_date(date);
            newEvent.set_title(title);
            newEvent.set_time(time);

            // set drawable
            newEvent.set_drawable(img);

            lstEvents.add(newEvent);

            adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

}

**Event Class**

```
public class Event {
public int _id;
public String _title;
public String _time;
public String _date;

//drawable
public Drawable _drawable;


public Event() {
    super();
};

public Event(int id, String title, String time, String date, Drawable drawable) {
    this._id = id;
    this._title = title;
    this._time = time;
    this._date = date;
    this._drawable = drawable;
};

public Event(JSONObject object){
    try {
        this._id = object.getInt("id");
        this._title = object.getString("title");
        this._time = object.getString("time");
        this._date = object.getString("date");
   } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public int get_Id() {
    return _id;
}


public String get_title() {
    return _title;
}

public void set_title(String _title) {
    this._title = _title;
}

public Drawable get_drawable() {
    return _drawable;
}

public void set_drawable(Drawable _drawable) {
    this._drawable = _drawable;
}

public String get_time() {
    return _time;
}

public void set_time(String _time) {
    this._time = _time;
}

public String get_date() {
    return _date;
}

public void set_date(String _date) {
    this._date = _date;
}
```

}

**EventAdapter**

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    //adding drawable to imageview
    ImageView img;
    TextView title;
    TextView time;
    TextView date;
}

public EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.date_detail);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Event event = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_detail, null);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);

        //adding drawable to imageview
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.title.setText(event._title);
    viewHolder.time.setText(event._time);
    viewHolder.date.setText(event._date);

    //drawable
    viewHolder.img.setImageDrawable(event._drawable);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}

**LogCat**

03-18 21:49:57.153: E/AndroidRuntime(6218): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 21:49:57.153: E/AndroidRuntime(6218): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.example.datetracker/.MainActivity (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.datetracker/com.example.datetracker.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
03-18 21:49:57.153: E/AndroidRuntime(6218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
03-18 21:49:57.153: E/AndroidRuntime(6218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
03-18 21:49:57.153: E/AndroidRuntime(6218):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:146)
03-18 21:49:57.153: E/AndroidRuntime(6218):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1288)

Comment: what you are getting in `resId = b.getInt("DRAWABLE");` line ?

Comment: I am not sure how I would check.

Comment: use `Log.e("SWAGSWAG","DRAWABLE"+resId);` then check logcat

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int resId = getResources().getInteger(R.id.btn_picture);
```

to

```
int resId = R.id.btn_picture;
```

because  `R.id.btn_picture` is already an integer id for view so no need to use `getResources().getInteger`;

Comment: This returns a value DRAWABLE 2131296262. I am still getting an error that says RESOURCE IS NOT A DRAWABLE. The error happens when Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(resId);, and newEvent.set_drawable(img); are uncommented.

I believe it is because I am trying to getDrawable() from an int, and not the actual button itself.